# Connecting to TortoiseSVN repository using AnkhSVN on VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am using AnkhSVN v2.5 and TortoiseSVN 1.9.4

I am not able to browse through the directories on my local drive.

[image: Screenshot]

Running as administrator didn't help either. However when using VisualSVN the issue is resolved. 
Unfortunately, I can only use AnkhSVN, please help.

Comment: _"Unfortunately, I can only use AnkhSVN"_. Is it some corporate restriction? You already use TortoiseSVN, so I guess that using VisualSVN with Visual Studio would be a natural choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TortoiseSVN 1.9.x is based on Subversion 1.9. Local repository it creates and that you access via `file:///` has [FSFS format 7](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.9.html#fsfs-format7), by default. This FSFS format is new in SVN 1.9; SVN 1.8 and older clients and servers will not be able to read this repository unless you dump-load its data into an clean repository with older format.

AnkhSVN 2.5.x is based on SVN 1.8 (via SharpSVN) and this explains why it is unable to access this repository. The problem is that AnkhSVN does not display full error message in your case. The error could help you find out what's going on. I'm not sure, but I guess that this is the error that AnkhSVN had to display in your case: `svnadmin: E125006: 'REPOS\db\format' contains invalid filesystem format option 'addressing physical'`.

These steps should help you solve the problem:

- Install VisualSVN Server or another Subversion server on Windows and access your repositories via HTTP(S) or svnserve instead of local `file:///` access. The repository internals will not matter for your client in this case as the client will communicate with the server, not with the repository directly. This will help you avoid such problems in future.
- Update to AnkhSVN 2.6.x. It should be compatible with SVN 1.9.x and Visual Studio 2012. I guess will access that repository without errors. I'm not sure, but I guess that there is no practical reason to use older AnkhSVN builds.